# Grafana prometheus with fastapi

Tags: python, prometheus, fastapi

I'm curious about this Prometheus, can I develop a Grafana with Prometheus as a data source with fastapi URL? Right now I'm developing on Grafana monitoring dashboard and I have an API using fastapi and I'm using this API as a data source with SimpleJSON plugin on Grafana. But now I'm a little curious about this Prometheus, is it possible to use my API as a Prometheus data source? If so, what endpoint that I should provide? For now for SimpleJSON Plugin it required `/`, `/search` and `/query`. How about Prometheus data sources?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Data source" means something specific in Grafana. Prometheus data source has a well defined path for its queries; you can't modify that. There is an HTTP JSON+API datasource for Grafana if you search its plugins - https://marcus.se.net/grafana-json-datasource/

However, that's completely bypassing Prometheus longer-term storage. Prometheus reads *scrape targets*, then collects and aggregates that.

To do so, your API would need to expose any route that returns Prometheus "exposition format", not JSON. This route is put in the Prometheus config file, not into Grafana anywhere.

While Prometheus can load random data, it's better to use Counter, Guage, etc types it expects

The OpenTelemetry project should be able to be used in any framework, and there are examples in their documentation for the Python module.

If your goal is to just get any data, not metrics, into Grafana, using an RDBMS or Mongodb, or other supported data sources might be better

Comment: So I can't modify my Endpoint API into Prometheus format? I can change my Endpoint API to adjust it into Prometheus, but as you said, it needs to return exposition format, and this route is put in the Prometheus config file right? How can I reach that?

Comment: You didn't say what your api currently returns. Sure, you can modify it. But reach what? The Prometheus server yaml file is on disk on the Prometheus server

Comment: My return from my API is JSON, but when I assign my API URL into Prometheus, it was said `Error reading Prometheus: client_error: client error: 404`, Is it I need to put my API URL into Prometheus server (Configurate on Prometheus YAML)?

Comment: Last I checked, Prometheus itself cannot read JSON formatted metrics, but a 404 would mean you gave it the wrong route. Besides, as answered, Grafana can read JSON sources, and doesn't require Prometheus

Comment: But, can I return my API to plain/text to do the same as Prometheus metrics return? You said it was the wrong route, but I can access my API successfully

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to manually change anything when you could simply add the OpenTelemetry module to your project and add a new route for it